# Is it possible to make lists using WITH clause in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a list of items A, B, C, D, E which are not present in a table but are hard-coded. can we create a list of sorts using with statement? Something like

```
WITH listname1 AS (item1, item2, item3,...)
SELECT x from table_x where x in listname1
```

Comment: You didn't see [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)?

Comment: I did, but didn't quite understand as there's no example of such a thing. Is a union statement necessary after each item?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It would be more complicated than just using `in (item1, item2, item3)`, especially if they're hard-coded,  and the code with `with` would be far less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `VALUES` clause inside the cte like this:

```
WITH listname1 AS (VALUES ('item1'), ('item2'), ('item3'))
SELECT x from table_x where x in listname1;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=29bce0ce7314cecf323a095318013c88).